# Very many lines in one plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I am trying to plot 21 lines in matplotlib from a csv file. I have made a "crude" plot using pandas by doing `df.plot(x='Date')`.[image]

I am however not having much success using matplotlib. Things I have tried so far:

```
# Start by creating figure and axis
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))

# Plot the data
ax.plot(df['Date'], df['1 Heildartekjur'], label='Heildartekjur')
ax.plot(df['Date'], df['11 Skatttekjur'], label='Skatttekjur')
ax.plot(df['Date'], df['111 Skattar á tekjur og hagnað'], label='Skattar á tekjur og hagnað')
ax.plot(df['Date'], df['112 Skattar á launagreiðslur og vinnuafl'], label='Skattar á launagreiðslur og vinnuafl')
ax.plot(df['Date'], df['113 Eignarskattar'], label='Eignarskattar')

ax.legend();
```

This works fine, but as soon as I add one more line I get an error:

```
# Start by creating figure and axis
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))

# Plot the data
ax.plot(df['Date'], df['1 Heildartekjur'], label='Heildartekjur')
ax.plot(df['Date'], df['11 Skatttekjur'], label='Skatttekjur')
ax.plot(df['Date'], df['111 Skattar á tekjur og hagnað'], label='Skattar á tekjur og hagnað')
ax.plot(df['Date'], df['112 Skattar á launagreiðslur og vinnuafl'], label='Skattar á launagreiðslur og vinnuafl')
ax.plot(df['Date'], df['113 Eignarskattar'], label='Eignarskattar')
ax.plot(df['Date'], df['114 Skattar vöru og þjónustu'], label='Skattar á vöru og þjónustu')

ax.legend();
```

`KeyError: '114 Skattar vöru og þjónustu'` I did copy/paste this from the csv file, so spelling should not be an issue.

I have tried `df.unstack(fill_value=0).plot()`

`image = ax.plot(df['Date'], df)` gives error:

`ValueError: view limit minimum -36866.545000000006 is less than 1 and is an invalid Matplotlib date value. This often happens if you pass a non-datetime value to an axis that has datetime units` but 'Date' is a datetime units.

I haven't found anything that could help me on the matplotlib documentation site. I am not trying any `for` loops, just want the `Date` to be on the x axis. Most of the tutorial I find on the internet have 3 lines and use `df.plot(x, x, legend='Legend')` 3 times.
I am not sure how I can share the csv file, but I would be happy to do that.

I am pretty sure this is easy, but I haven't figured this out yet :D

Comment: Have you tried only plotting the line you are trying to add (the one with number 114)? Maybe there is a problem with the Umlaut.

Comment: I noticed that I did spacing error in there, but there must be easier way to plot all instead of making 20 lines of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a spacing error in the command, it should be`ax.plot(df['Date'], df['114 Skattar  vöru og þjónustu'], label='Skattar á vöru og þjónustu]')`. Works fine. Still think it should be easier to plot all of the data :D

Sorry for putting up a question for no reason.